# Windows 7 refusing to install due to a partition error during installation

Tags: windows-7, installation, format

When I started my computer, it gave me this error:

> Disk error occurred. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> 
>   <kbd>Del</kbd> to restart.

or

> Reboot and select proper boot device, or insert boot media in selected
>   boot device and press any key.

As a solution, I started a new installation of Window 7 from a pen drive. It started but when I got to selecting the partition to install, it gives me this error:

> Windows could not format a partition on disk 0 - error code
>   0x80070057.

Comment: one thing to note here is mother board cell is not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code 0x80070057 appears because the **partition that is reserved for system is damaged**

Inorder to solve the issue try by `deleting the existing partitions, create a new partition, and continue with the formatting` ,This Microsoft [forum](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2476568) gives you elaborated answer

Apart from that Reboot and select proper boot device, or insert boot media in selected boot device and press any key ,try **re-arranging your boot order of your bios with respective to your booting device will solve your problem**.

Comment: is it possible to get my data from harddisk

Comment: @RAHUL you would need some sort of offline backup tool in order to accomplish that. You should also run a disk test tool for your hard drive, it's possible that it's failing.

Comment: deleting only system partition and installing windows again worked..Thanks