# Not able to format HDD while installing windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

I am asking this new question after trying to recover my crashed windows data
please refer below question/link

[How to recover data from crashed Windows laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/814893/how-to-recover-data-from-crashed-windows-laptop)

-------------**My query regarding HDD Format Issue**-----------------

windows is not able to neither format HDD nor install windows.IT gives following error

while formatting: Windows could not format a partition on disk 0. Error code: 0x80070057
While installing:It is not able to recognize HDD format so it doesn't go to next installation step

I used following steps to format HDD

diskpart

list disk

select disk 0

clean

format

It couldn't execute format

Comment: Are you trying to Upgrade from 7 to 8.1 or a clean install? How did you format it, was it using cmd in the installation disk or from your existing Windows installation?

Comment: I have updated my question;

I am trying to install windows on crashed OS/windows

Comment: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2476568

Comment: In support2.microsoft.com/kb/2476568 my system directly shows step 10 i.e unallocated space as 474GB & when i perform step 11 & 12 it fails to do show.....any alternative ??

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Since you are unable to format it from the Windows installation disk, do it using [GParted Live CD.](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php): (Detailed instructions are provided at the [GParted Live Manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-delete-partition) website).

1. Select an unmounted partition. Choose: Partition → Delete. The application displays the delete partition operation in the Pending Operations pane.
2. Now format it. Choose: Partition → Format to, and select a type of file system from the list eg FAT32/NTFS.

If even this doesn't work then go for [Western Digital Diagnostics Disk](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=613&sid=30&lang=en)- The usage of this can also be achieved using the **dd** command in a terminal.

---

The error code 0x80070057 appears because [the partition that is reserved for system is damaged](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2476568)

To resolve this problem, delete the existing partitions, create a new partition, and continue with the formatting.

•  Start the installation process.

•  Select all appropriate settings then click **Install now.**

•  Click **Custom (Advanced)**.

•  Select **Disk 0 partition 1**, and click **Delete**.

•  Select **Disk 0 partition 2**, and click **Delete.**

•  Click **New**.

•  Define the size of the disk, and then click **Apply**.

*Note: the size of the default value is the maximum size of the disk.*

•  Select **Disk 0 partition 2**, and then click **Formatting**.

•  Formatting should complete correctly. Click **Next** to continue.

You can now complete the installation without problems.

[Similar superuser question.](https://superuser.com/questions/652223/windows-7-refusing-to-install-due-to-a-partition-error-during-installation)

Comment: 1. I have single partition so there is no **delete** option

2. **Format** tab is disabled

3. When i click on **New** & give a value which is less than total memory lets say 250GB out of 476GB; its not able to create new partition